# Mac OS X Spyder's IPython Console Stuck in "Connecting to Console"

Tags: python, macos, console, ipython, spyder

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.5.

I installed Spyder using the `spyder-2.3.3-py3.4.dmg` from https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/downloads.

When I launch Spyder, I get an error (posted at the bottom), but Spyder still opens.  However, the IPython console is stuck

> "connecting to kernel"

I've seen the post [Ipython console in Spyder stuck on "connecting to kernel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802860/ipython-console-in-spyder-stuck-on-connecting-to-kernel?rq=1), but I'm not running on Windows and I didn't install Spyder via Python(x,y).

It might be worth noting that first I did try to install Spyder by using Macports.  I mentioned this because maybe something is clashing.

Here is the error I get when I launch Spyder:
    Process:         Spyder [20918]
    Path:            /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/Spyder
    Identifier:      Spyder
    Version:         ???
    Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:  Spyder [20907]
    Responsible:     Spyder [20907]
    User ID:         501

```
Date/Time:       2015-03-25 08:52:40.680 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  D0BBA20B-FE9F-8FEA-2F26-6084411D31FC

Sleep/Wake UUID: 70ED8E3B-7222-465C-9ED7-F026908F1D1A

Crashed Thread:  Unknown

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff5fc01028

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x000000000000000e  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x0000000000000000
r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
rip: 0x00007fff5fc01028  rfl: 0x0000000000010203  cr2: 0x00007fff5fc01028

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000014
Trap Number:     14


Binary images description not available


External Modification Summary:
Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by all processes on this machine:
task_for_pid: 23636
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 114
```

I also noticed these in the Console application:

```
3/25/15 8:52:37.683 AM ReportCrash[20914]: Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef for Spyder[20913]
3/25/15 8:52:38.124 AM ReportCrash[20914]: Failed to create dSYM-less CSSymbolicatorRef for Spyder[20913]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just solved the same problem for myself, although it was on Windows7. I think the cause is the same.

For me, I used Python(x,y) to install everything initially. Later, I decided to uninstall Python(x,y) and install all the packages one by one. Somehow, the previous setting of Spyder was not removed. So the new installation keeps looking for IPython using the Python(x,y) related setting, which is no longer correct.

SOLUTION: I went to the user folder and deleted all the .ipython and .spyder files. Then reopened Spyder and everything works. Try the similar thing on your Mac.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting all the .ipython ... files from the home directory works for Mac El Captain.

Comment: It will be great if you will add some details in your answer