# IPython console stuck on "Connecting to kernel..." (Spyder v3.2.6, Py 3.6, Windows 10, 64x)

Tags: python, kernel, ipython, spyder

Please bear with me, as I'm new to python and Stackoverflow.

When starting Spyder (v3.2.6), my IPython console gets stuck on ***"Connecting to kernel..."***

All the solutions to similar inquiries that I can find seem to involve Anaconda, which I don't have installed (to my knowledge), and would prefer not to unless its absolutely necessary.

I've tried *opening new IPython consoles*, *restarting the kernel*, *restarting Spyder*, *resetting Spyder to factor default settings*, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check all the proposed solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802860/ipython-console-in-spyder-stuck-on-connecting-to-kernel)?

Comment: Hi Georgy, thanks for the quick reply. Most the solutions refer to Anaconda.. I haven't tried "uninstalling and reinstalling python(x,y) and deleting related folders (.ipython and .spyder3) in the user folder" which seemed to work for someone in the past. This sounds basically like a full re-install to me (that also didn't work for all users), so I'm leaving it for a last resort :)

Comment: I suggest to read through all the issues about the same problem on their [github repo](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+sort%3Aupdated-desc+is%3Aclosed+connecting+to+kernel). Maybe you can find solution for your specific case.

Comment: Hey Georgy, thanks for the link! [#6452](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6452) worked (solution is to switch graphics mode from Automatic to TK). Not sure how this will affect my day-to-day operations, but we'll see :)

Answer (score 5):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This bug was introduced by the latest update to Pyzmq (17.0.0). The easiest way to solve this is to downgrade to Pyzmq **16.0.4** until a new version of Ipykernel is released (most probably 4.8.2).

Comment: How one does that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "Environments" in the Anaconda Navigator.
2. Search for pyzmq
3. Click on the green tick box and select version 16.0.3
4. Click on "Apply"

That's it, it should work after that. I had the same issue and it got resolved after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Also had the same problem, details in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63960983/8554602).

So my advice is to switch your working project to a new project, then watch whether this problem could happen again. If not, check your `file name` in the project by moving files out and see whether this problem could happen.

For me, I found that a file named `decorator.py` may be the problem. But still don't know why, if somebody knows, please tell me.